# In GCP, Migrating project to an organization isn't working

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to migrate a project with "no organization" to an existing one

I've tried selecting organization and clicking on migrate

[image]

But I just received this message and nothing happened

[image]

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76414315/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: @LorenaGomez it didn't work, but I appreciate the effort

Comment: @Abedshmaytilli I'm willing to help, let me know if you followed the steps using an incognito window and if the error message is the same or a different one

Comment: @SamuelLopez I have the owner permission for all project with no organization, but when I migrate them in incognito window, I get the same issue as described in this post

Comment: One of these methods should help you see the error. 1) Open the browser `Inspect` window. Go to the Network tab. Repeat the process using the browser. I am guessing that you will see an error for one of the HTTP requests. 2) Another option is to use the CLI. This page shows the command: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/moving-projects-folders#gcloud

Comment: @JohnHanley I received this error
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n5j)[InjectionToken MatMdcDialogData -> InjectionToken MatMdcDialogData -> InjectionToken MatMdcDialogData]: 
  mb`InjectionToken MatMdcDialogData

ERROR Error: hb`TypeError: a is undefined`
e5a/<@https://www.gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/js/k=pantheon.pantheon_module_set.en_US.Ic3H9DEIf8s.O/am=EIf_Ar-Mf0gDCCkAELJGAAIBWIBkAgAYMRcAAwQg/d=1/rs=ADqnUbN0pLEDWZvqh4A9hc1BfZYTcLKhSw/m=core:1427:413
jc@https://www.gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/js/k=pantheon.pantheon_

Comment: Assuming that those errors are in the browser Inspect window, there are other problems that happened earlier in the window. Blocked script or something like that. Do you have anti-virus or ad-blocking software installed? I recommend that you use the CLI `gcloud` for this task. Later, figure out what is installed on your system that is messing up your browser connections to GCP. You will continue to have problems. Edit your post with details on the Inspect window errors so that others can easily read them.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this, I tried using the gcloud CLI and then I get an error saying the user (who is a principle/owner) doesn't have permission to access the project instance...

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a role, so make sure the user who is migrating the project has some specific roles on the destination organization side and the no organization side. I've been able to migrate a project from No organization to an organization, please take a look at the roles I assigned my user for the project located in **No organization:**

[image]

Now this is the role I assigned to the **destination organization:**

[image]

Go to the Manage resources page: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager locate the project you need to migrate from No organization > click on the 3 dots and click on "Migrate" select the new organization where you want to migrate the project.

References:

- [Migrating projects with no organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/handle-special-cases#migrating_projects_no_org)
- [Assign Identity and Access Management roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/assign-iam-roles)